# Null reference in loop?

Tags: apex, trigger, controller-extension, extension

I'm getting this error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

when I'm trying to pass child records to new record creation(`order_LIne_item__c`).

Here I have nested Query and I'm passing inner query(child) values to for loop for creating a new record in `order_LIne_item__c`.

```
for(Quote_line_item__c qlis : fixOrder.Quote_Line_Items__r){
            ORLI= new order_LIne_item__c();

           if (qlis.Name != null){
               ORLI.Name=qlis.Name;
           }
           if (qlis.Description__c!= null){
               ORLI.Description__c=qlis.Description__c;
           }
           if (qlis.Client_P_N__c!= null){
               ORLI.client_Pn__c=qlis.Client_P_N__c;
           }
           System.debug(ORLI);
          if (ORLI!= null){
             ORINlist.add(ORLI);//addding into the LIST
             } 

         }
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `ORINlist` variable and assign with `List<order_LIne_item__c>`.

So, initially and out of for loop, do this

```
List<order_LIne_item__c> ORINlist = new List<order_LIne_item__c>();
```

Comment: How can I assign like that I want to pass values to `order_Line_item__c`, & create a new record in order line items

Comment: my bad, updated the line